# Showing a summation of powers of a prime power $q$

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic, finite-fields

I calculated that the number of rank $k$ matrices in $\mathbb{F}_q^{n \times m}$ (where we may assume $n \leq m$) for a prime power $q$ is equal to

$$W_{n,m}(k) := \prod_{i = 1}^k \frac{(q^m - q^{i-1})(q^n - q^{i-1})}{(q^k - q^{i-1})}$$

And so summing all $W_{n,m}(k)$ from rank $k = 0$ to full rank $k = n$ should gives us all matrices of $\mathbb{F}_q^{n \times m}$

$$\sum_{k = 0}^n W_{n,m}(k) = q^{nm}$$

Can we also show this equality using pure arithmetic and combinatorial tricks, i.e. using just the formulas for $W_{n,m}$?

Comment: I did backtrace the original result, where there also seemed to be some surprise about the equality: [5] G. Landsberg, Über eine Anzahlbestimmung und eine damit zusammenhängende Reihe, J. Reine Angew. Math. 111 (1893) 87–88.

Comment: I think I may have solved it by applying induction on equation A from the original paper. Equation A can be shown directly from the q-analogue of Pascal's identity for binomial coefficients, which is only based on calculations and counting. This reduces everything to counting, without using any argument from linear algebra. I'll write this out when I have time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this, but it took a number of pages. The full answer can be found [here](https://krijnreijnders.files.wordpress.com/2020/10/counting_matrices_finite_field.pdf).

In short: one can show that the following $q$-analogue of Pascal's rule holds:
$$\prod_{i=1}^k \frac{q^{n+1} - q^{i-1}}{q^k - q^{i-1}} = q^k \cdot \prod_{i=1}^k \frac{q^{n} - q^{i-1}}{q^k - q^{i-1}} + \prod_{i=1}^{k-1} \frac{q^{n} - q^{i-1}}{q^{k-1} - q^{i-1}}$$

Then, this allows you to show that
$$
W_{n+1,m}(k) = q^k\cdot W_{n,m}(k) + (q^m - q^{k-1})\cdot W_{n,m}(k-1)
$$
by multiplying both sides with $\prod (q^m - q^{i-1})$.

Lastly, use induction on $n$ to get the final equality.

(Fun challenge, try to find the linear algebra interpretation of each statement)